# Optimizing the process of joining multiple tables in SQL using LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework-core

There are five tables to join.
I have successfully joined them together, but I believe there is room for optimization. Initially, I had to apply a 'group by' operation on the 'comments' table and then utilize its first row to obtain the count of comments.

```cs
var groupedComments = _context.UsersPhotoComments.GroupBy(
        p => p.UsersPhotosId, p => p.Comment, (key, g) => new { PhotoId = key, Count = g.Count() });

var photos =
    (
    from p in _context.UsersPhotos
    join albums in _context.UsersAlbums on p.UsersAlbumsId equals albums.Id into GroupAlbums
    from albums in GroupAlbums.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join info in _context.UsersInformation on albums.UsersId equals info.UsersId into GroupUser
    from info in GroupUser.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where (info.Username == req.Username)
    select new
    {
        Photos = p,
    }
    )
    .OrderBy(p => p.Photos.InsertDate)
    .Select(p => new GetUsersInformationPhotosByUsernameServiceDto
    {
        Filename = p.Photos.Filename,
        Id = p.Photos.Id,
        Title = p.Photos.Title,
        Detail = p.Photos.Detail,
        VisitorCounter = p.Photos.VisitorCounter + 1,
        CountComments = groupedComments.Where(gc => gc.PhotoId == p.Photos.Id).Select(gc => gc.Count).First().ToString(),
    })
    .Take(6)
    .ToList();
```

[image: you can find here the final output]

Comment: Hi, could you develop what do you mean by "there is room for optimization" ? What do you want to optimize ? Readability ? Performance ?

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply. Actually, both of them, but without a shadow of a doubt the performance is more important to me.

Comment: What you can do is ordering inside your first part of the linq code. https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-sorting-operators-orderby-orderbydescending
With that you can remove your first select statement and then the `OrderBy` method, you will improve a little bit I think

Comment: And if you need to improve the query you can create a view and query it to retrieve all the data you need, you can do that with the `[Keyless]` attribute but it will depend on the version of EF you are using, it's only available on EF Core. "This feature was added in EF Core 2.1 under the name of query types. In EF Core 3.0 the concept was renamed to keyless entity types. The [Keyless] Data Annotation became available in EFCore 5.0." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: Add your entity classes. I believe no any joins are needed, everything can be done via navigation properties.

Comment: @Ali.MEghbaldar that's not how EF or any ORM is meant to be used. ORMs try to give the impression of working with related in-memory objects, not tables and rows. The ORM itself generates JOINs if needed, from the entities and relations between them